# Plotly: How to manually specify the label of an aggregated field in plotly.py

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

In [Plotly.py](https://plotly.com/python/) [histogram](https://plotly.com/python/histograms/) and [Density heatmaps](https://plotly.com/python/2D-Histogram/) an aggregation function (`histfunc`) such as `sum` or `avg` may be specified.
The `x` and (unaggregated) `y` axis labels can be manually specified via the `labels` dict, but what about the label of the *aggregated dimension?*

**How can the label of the aggregated dimension be manually specified?**

[image: Example histogram for code below]

```py
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.tips()
fig = px.histogram(
    df,
    x="total_bill",
    y="tip",
    histfunc="avg",
    labels={"total_bill": "Total bill", "tip": "Tip", "??": "Average tip"},
)
fig.show()
```

### Update/Added

And what about the `z` axis (?) label for a [density heatmap](https://plotly.com/python/2D-Histogram/)?

[image: Density heatmap]

```py
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.iris()

fig = px.density_heatmap(
    df, x="petal_length", y="petal_width", z="sepal_length", histfunc="avg"
)
fig.show()
```

Comment: perhaps a custom histfunc that wraps avg and overrides label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title of the color bar can be set as follows.

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.iris()

fig = px.density_heatmap(
    df, x="petal_length", y="petal_width", z="sepal_length", histfunc="avg"
)
fig.layout['coloraxis']['colorbar']['title'] = 'new colorbar_title'
fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function update_layout to set y axis label. Example:

```
px.histogram(
    df,
    x="total_bill",
    y="tip",
    histfunc="avg",
    labels={"total_bill": "Total bill", "tip": "Tip", "??": "Average tip"},
).update_layout(yaxis_title="label for Y axis")
```

Comment: thanks for the fast solution! How about the `z` axis (?) label for density heatmaps? See updated question ;-)

Comment: I wish I could give you both (you and @r-beginners) the accepted answer 